# AutoLayout for a Dynamic number of Views

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, autolayout

I have a `UIView` at the bottom of a `UIViewController` that can have a different number of views added.

```
NSUInteger letterCount = [word length];

        NSLog(@"The word letter count is: %ld",(unsigned long)letterCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < letterCount; i++) {
            NSLog(@"new view being created");

            UIView *letterTileView = [UIView autolayoutView];
            letterTileView.tag = 600 + i;
            [self.bottomBarView addSubview:letterTileView];
        }
```

The word could be any word and therefore have a different number of letters. If the word is APPLE it would create 5 subviews in the bottom bar view.

I would like to use Auto Layout to layout these views. Each view should be 48x48 (height x width). I would like these subviews to be centered in the bottom bar view and have padding in between them.

I have used the following method to setup AL before but unsure how to approach the dynamic situation and laying these out correctly.

```
+ (NSArray *)constraintsWithVisualFormat:(NSString *)format  options:(NSLayoutFormatOptions)opts  metrics:(NSDictionary *)metrics  views:(NSDictionary *)views
```

Comment: Adding constraints in code is a common and easy thing to do. Indeed, Apple provides sample code that shows how to do it (in a situation very much like what you describe.) What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Can you share the example they provide where the situation is like mine. The documentation on Auto Layout is in fact very limited. The issue I have is that I am trying to layout a dynamic amount of views like this |-[view1]-[view2]-[view3]-|. But unsure how to build the constraint during the view creation

Comment: Watch the WWDC 2012 video on autolayout and the downloadable code that goes with it, for instance. There is a game with letter tiles arranged in a row that's amazingly similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example from my book, where I generate a bunch of UILabels programmatically and add constraints to them as I go along. It's not the same as your situation (my labels are arranged vertically) but it shows how easy it is to add constraints as you are creating interface dynamically:

```
UILabel* previousLab = nil;
for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
    UILabel* lab = [UILabel new];
    // lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    lab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is label %d", i+1];
    [v addSubview:lab];
    [v addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[lab]"
                                             options:0 metrics:nil
                                               views:@{@"lab":lab}]];
    if (!previousLab) { // first one, pin to top
        [v addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[lab]"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:@{@"lab":lab}]];
    } else { // all others, pin to previous
        [v addConstraints: 
         [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[prev]-(10)-[lab]"
          options:0 metrics:nil
          views:@{@"lab":lab, @"prev":previousLab}]];
    }
    previousLab = lab;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matt - I was able to use a method that does similar to your answer above. It also adds another constraint after the loop for the [previousView] to the superview. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have been looking for a solution like this. I however have a set of fields in one view (like a form with label and input) as a single row. All other rows will fall below this. Thanks a lot @matt

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is create the visual format string dynamically based on the number of views you'll have. Some sample code:

```
NSArray *views = @[view1, view2, view3]; // this would be a dynamic array with views

NSMutableString *vflString = [NSMutableString string];
NSMutableDictionary *viewsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
    NSString *viewIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"view%d", i];
    [vflString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-[%@]-", viewIdentifier];
    viewsDictionary[viewIdentifier] = views[i];
}

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vflString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

You can change metrics and positioning and stuff like that too, of course.

Comment: This would not work for me as you are passing into the vflString the viewIdentifier but that is simply a string created not the actual name of the pointer to the view. How can I dynamically create a pointer name to my new views so that the names are passed in correctly for my example?

Comment: @StuartM Look at what @Scott is showing you. The `viewsDictionary` is the "pointer" to your new views.

Comment: @StuartM: The actual name of the variable that points to the view doesn't matter. In many cases, using `NSDictionaryMakeWithVariableBindings()` helps make the link between key and view easy, but you don't **have** to use it.